# Linking googleTest in VS2010 results in LNK2005 because of other dependent libraries

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker-errors, googletest, lnk2005

I have a large and complicated project that is finally getting unit tests. I've built googleTest 1.6.0 locally with Visual Studio 2010, the project files built with cmake as the README specifies.

This project has many dependent libraries that are statically and dynamically linked. Many of them proprietary. All attempts to link generate 220 such errors. Here is a sampling:

> > > msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all(void)" (?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QEAAXXZ) already defined in gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj)
> > >
> > > libcpmtd.lib(cerr.obj) : error LNK2005: "protected: char * __cdecl std::basic_streambuf >::_Gndec(void)" (?_Gndec@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IEAAPEADXZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll)
> > >
> > > LIBCMTD.lib(setlocal.obj) : error LNK2005: _configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR100D.dll)
> > >
> > > LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
> > >       LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
> > >
> > > fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

I've tried the /NODEFAULTLIB flag, and I've tried to ignore just msvcprtd.lib, MSVCRTD.lib, and LIBCMTD.lib, as suggested, but then I suffer from unresolved symbols...

Both the project and googleTest are compiled with x64, /MP, /MDd, and no /clr.

I've been playing around with compiler flags, wondering if there's some sort of version mismatch. Dumpbin, to the extent with which I understand it, hasn't hinted anything I might understand. I was hoping for an er

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like your question is answered in Google Talk's [FAQ](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/faq.md#i-am-building-my-project-with-google-test-in-visual-studio-and-all-im-getting-is-a-bunch-of-linker-errors-or-warnings-help). Make sure all your libraries use the /MD(d) setting.

> You may get a number of the following linker error or warnings if you attempt to link your test project with the Google Test library when your project and the are not built using the same compiler settings.
>
> - LNK2005: symbol already defined in object
> - LNK4217: locally defined symbol 'symbol' imported in function 'function'
> - LNK4049: locally defined symbol 'symbol' imported
>     The Google Test project (gtest.vcproj) has the Runtime Library option set to /MT (use multi-threaded static libraries, /MTd for debug). If your project uses something else, for example /MD (use multi-threaded DLLs, /MDd for debug), you need to change the setting in the Google Test project to match your project's.
>
> To update this setting open the project properties in the Visual Studio IDE then select the branch Configuration Properties | C/C++ | Code Generation and change the option "Runtime Library". You may also try using gtest-md.vcproj instead of gtest.vcproj.

Comment: It turns out you are correct. I had forgotten I had posted this question before I stumbled across the answer through my own trial.

Comment: Although several years old, could u plz fix the (now) incorrect FAQ link to: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/FAQ.md#i-am-building-my-project-with-google-test-in-visual-studio-and-all-im-getting-is-a-bunch-of-linker-errors-or-warnings-help